# Download images via 1 button

Tags: html, canvas, download, html2canvas

I have a problem to download images via 1 button. Now my situation is pressed the preview button first then click the download link just can download the images. How can direct pressed the download link to download the images?

Below is my tried the sample coding:

```html
<div id="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
  <strong>Testing</strong>
  <hr/>
  <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
    Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
  </h3>
  <p style="color: #3e4b51;">
    <b>Codepedia.info</b> is a programming blog. Tutorials focused on Programming ASP.Net, C#, jQuery, AngularJs, Gridview, MVC, Ajax, Javascript, XML, MS SQL-Server, NodeJs, Web Design, Software</p>
  <p style="color: #3e4b51;">
    <b>html2canvas</b> script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation.
  </p>
</div>
<input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview" />
<a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
<br/>

<div id="previewImage">
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
    var getCanvas; // global variable

    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function() {
      html2canvas(element, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
          $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
          getCanvas = canvas;
        }
      });
    });

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function() {
      var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
      var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
      $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
    });
  });
</script>
```

The output result like below the picture:

[image: sample1]

Hope someone can guide me how to remove the preview button and just click the download link can download the images.

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ason5861_cs/7c14gLxn/1/

Comment: How you generate the preview? How you implemented the download? It will help us to see also you javascript code. Or, even better, create a working demo using built-in snippet or codepen, jsbin, codesandbox etc.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ason5861_cs/7c14gLxn/1/ Thanks for your comment. This is my working fiddle

Comment: @MoshFeu Have you idea to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your download function a bit so it can be reusable.

```js
$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'your_pic_name.png';
  link.href = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png")
  link.click();
});
```

This way, you can trigger the download just by

```js
$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").trigger('click');
```

So the preview code is

```js
$('#btn-Preview-Image').on('click', function () {
  html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
      $('#previewImage').append(canvas);
      getCanvas = canvas;

      $('#btn-Convert-Html2Image').trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

https://output.jsbin.com/gimumoq

Comment: Thanks your answer, how to hide the preview image when I've clicked the previous button

Comment: I have new question related this questoin, if you have free, can look my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62149036/images-cannot-save-into-the-localhost-folder-location?noredirect=1#comment109917015_62149036

Comment: About your first question, I believe that you can just remove `$('#previewImage').append(canvas);`

Comment: Ok. Do you have any method image can send to the localhost server? If can't I need to find out other way to solve it

Comment: Because my client said that must save in the server

Comment: Let's continue in the original question. Anyway, if it should be in the server it opens a whole new territory. What server you gonna use (node, java, php etc.) But again, let's continue in the original question.

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin

Comment: Then I am using php language

Comment: Thanks you take time to guide me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215164/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-sunny-ong).